# Как на Wordpress при нажатии кнопки перемещаться на активный экран меню?

Tags: wordpress

как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меню, экран опускался на соответствующий блок. Например, нажал на Контакты, экран плавно спустился к этому блоку, нажал на Новости, экран спустился на блок новостей

сам сайт http://tempest.beget.tech/
демо, как должно быть https://yadi.sk/i/rBn-qBpqjupa6Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть чуть дополню ответ SeVlad:

1. В меню делаешь ссылки типа #contact
2. Нужной секции на сайте задаешь id = 'contact
3. Для плавного скрола добавляешь такой стиль:

   html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
   }

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меню, экран опускался на
> соответствующий блок. Например, нажал на Контакты, экран плавно
> спустился к этому блоку, нажал на Новости, экран спустился на блок
> новостей

Это называется якоря. См http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

В меню создаётся произвольная ссылка с именем якоря (например `#news`), а в нужном блоке задаётся это имя ( `name="news"`).